# c3.js donut chart onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

I have created a C3js donut chart in my website, I have assigned a `onclick` function in the chart and I'd like to have a button to fire the function too but, I cannot figure any good approach to do it.

I tried to create a button in order to fire the function like below, find the element and bind it to my `.onclick()` function:

```
  $("#test").click(function(){
        $(".c3-arc-data2").click();
  });
```

But it doesn't work.

Please see the example in the fiddleJS:https://jsfiddle.net/mcd6ucge/52/

**Extension:**

I have an if statement for the section, which will change the data of the chart and when the data has been alter to another case the `onclick` function is not working

```
    if(x = "something"){
        $(".uldateBtn1").html(
        '<li id="test-fliter" class="dateBtn hvr-underline-from-left" style="margin-top:10px !important;">test</li>'
                                )

        $("#test-fliter").click(function(){

          var evt = new MouseEvent("click");//make a mouse event
          d3.select(".c3-arc-test").node().dispatchEvent(evt);

         });
    }

else{
 $(".uldateBtn1").html(
    '<li id="test2-fliter" class="dateBtn hvr-underline-from-left" style="margin-top:10px !important;">test</li>'
                            )

    $("#test2-fliter").click(function(){

      var evt = new MouseEvent("click");//make a mouse event
      d3.select(".c3-arc-test2").node().dispatchEvent(evt);

     });

}
```

The if is working fine but the else is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it like this

```
  $("#test").click(function(){
    var evt = new MouseEvent("click");//make a mouse event
    //dispatch the event on the element.
    d3.select(".c3-arc-data1").node().dispatchEvent(evt);
 });
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8uhwj7qp/)

Comment: Thanks! such a good answer. Getting it's node and trigger is a good thought!